# Unable to read attribute set by Razor through jQuery, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

`console.log(myvar)` shows `undefined` when it shouldn't be. The last `console.log shows` exactly the full tag, where I can see that `data-mydata` has a value. Why is this happening?

```html
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<div class="row">
  <label class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
    <input type="radio" class="myclass" id="@item.Id" name="myname" onchange="myHandler()" value="@item.property" data-mydata="@Html.Encode(item.property2)"/>
    @item.Name
  </label>
</div>
}

<script>
  function myHandler() {
    var myvar = $(this).data('mydata');
    console.log(myvar);
    console.log($("input[name='myName']:checked")[0]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Check the actual HTML output of `data-mydata="@Html.Encode(item.property2)"`. It's likely that the output is breaking HTML syntax, most likely from incorrect quotes.

Comment: Also note that `onX` attributes are very outdated and should no longer be used. Use [unobtrusive event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `this` to `myHandler`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<div class="row">
  <label class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
    <input type="radio" class="myclass" id="@item.Id" name="myname" onchange="myHandler(this)" value="@item.property" data-mydata="@Html.Encode(item.property2)"/>
    @item.Name
  </label>
</div>
}

<script>
  function myHandler(t) {
    var myvar = $(t).data('mydata');
    console.log(myvar);
    console.log($("input[name='myName']:checked")[0]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, in the end I got it working, but the question is why the previous didn't work? why mydata is undefined?

Comment: Because the `this` in your code is not the input,it is `Window`.